# How do I call an attribute value from one model class to another model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an attribute called `ServiceName` in my `Service.cs` class, and I want the same value to show in another class called `Booking.cs` without me having to enter it again.

```
public class Service
{
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}



public class Booking
{    
    [DisplayName("Service Chosen")]
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: What if `Booking` inherits from `Service`?

Answer (score 0):

So you must communicate between two class so you must use something like Prism EventAggregator
With this you can send value if its change like

```
public string ServiceName
{
    get { return _serviceName; }
    set
    {
        _serviceName = value;
        EventAggregator.GetEvent<eventname>().Publish(_serviceName);
    }
}
```

and subscribe using `EventAggregator.GetEvent<eventname>().Subscribe(YourSubscribeMethod);`

you can read about it here https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/event-aggregator.html